# Moving text to specified position using xsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I don't even know what terms to search for. I'm a beginner with xml and xslt and am looking to create html output from a xml file. My problem looks like this:

The text in my xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
<p>This is some text. This is the last bit of text.</p>
<add>This is some other <hi>text</hi>.</add>
</body>
```

The output I want in my html is

```
<p>This is some text. This is some other <hi>text</hi>. This is the last bit of text.<p>
```

I cannot just tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
<p><a>This is some text.</a> <b>This is the last bit of text.</b><p>
<c>This is some other <hi>text</hi>.</c>
</body>
```

What I want to do is place a marker for where the text needs to be inserted. Sort of like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
<p>This is some text. <insert n="1"/> This is the last bit of text.<p>
<addition n="1">This is some other <hi>text</hi>.</addition>
</body>
```

The added text can be anywhere in the document, but it I can easily assign the n manually. Any ideas how to achieve this with my xslt stylesheet?

Edit: In some cases the text within  contains more tags with corresponding templates in the xsl. I tried solving this on my own, but could not figure out how to apply templates within a key, could someone point me to a solution?

Many thanks!

Marie

Comment: Re your edit: should we take the last piece as the **input** for the XSL transformation?

Comment: Yes, this is how I would like to tag my xml file. But I don't even know if THAT would be a good idea, considering I have no idea how my xslt document should pick up the text tagged <addition> and move it to where it says <insert/>. That is my question. Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me modify your example a bit, because I suspect that wherever there is an `<addition n="1">`, there will eventually be an `<addition n="2">` too.

Given the following **example input**:

```
<body>
    <p>Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth, <insert n="1"/>a new nation, conceived in liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that “all men are created equal.”</p>
    <p>Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived, and so dedicated, can long endure. <insert n="2"/>We come to dedicate a portion of it, as a final resting place for those who died here, that the nation might live. This we may, in all propriety do.</p>
    <addition n="1">upon this continent, </addition>
    <addition n="2">We are met on a great battle field of that war. </addition>
</body>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="add" match="addition" use="@n" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="insert">
    <xsl:value-of select="key('add', @n)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="addition"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
  <p>Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth, upon this continent, a new nation, conceived in liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that “all men are created equal.”</p>
  <p>Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived, and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battle field of that war. We come to dedicate a portion of it, as a final resting place for those who died here, that the nation might live. This we may, in all propriety do.</p>
</body>
```

---

### Edit:

In view of your added requirement, change:

```
<xsl:template match="insert">
    <xsl:value-of select="key('add', @n)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="insert">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('add', @n)/node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```